# Replace pixel value in RGBA numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have a 2D array of RGBA values (Ex: `[30, 60, 90, 255]`) and I want to replace all white `[255 255 255 255]` with `[0 0 0 0]`. What is the simplest way to do this?

Using for loops I have tried assigning a new array to an index but the index does not change:

```
data = np.array(img)
for y in range(img.size[0]):
    for x in range(img.size[1]):
        if (data[x][y] == [255, 255, 255, 255]).all():
            data[x][y] == [0, 0, 0, 0] # Doesn't change value at index?
```

Comment: Don't use nested loops: this is very inefficient. Use vectorized operations instead. Note that the `np.array` conversion may convert values to floats in the [0,1] range and not [0,255]. Not to mention only data may be modified and not img if it is a deep copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.all`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) to check all four values for each row and column:

```
>>> img = np.array([[[220, 119, 177, 145],
                     [255, 255, 255, 255]],

                    [[  3,  67,  69,  74],
                     [  1, 104, 120,  98]]])
```

Get the index mask with a boolean condition against `[255, 255, 255, 255]`:

```
>>> mask = np.all(img == [255, 255, 255, 255], axis=-1)
array([[False,  True],
       [False, False]])
```

At this point, you can either assign a four element list or one element using `mask`:

```
>>> img[mask] = 0
array([[[220, 119, 177, 145],
        [  0,   0,   0,   0]],

       [[  3,  67,  69,  74],
        [  1, 104, 120,  98]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data[x][y] == [0, 0, 0, 0] # Doesn't change value at index?
```

should be :

```
data[x][y] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Definitely didn't notice that careless mistake lmao